# why does time.Parse parse the time incorrectly?

Tags: time, go

I'm trying to [parse](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) a string as time with but unfortunately go gets the wrong month (January instead of June)

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {

    t := "2014-06-23T20:29:39.688+01:00"
    tc, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000+01:00", t)
    
    fmt.Printf("t was %v and tc was %v", t, tc)

}
```

[Play](http://play.golang.org/p/mbOXZydHvT)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that your timezone offset is ill-defined in the layout: the reference offset is `-0700`. You defined yours as `+01:00`, so the `01` is interpreted as the month and erase the previously defined one. And as your working offset is `01` as well, it is parsed as january.

The following example works for me [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/yKzPpHLLik)

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {

    t := "2014-06-23T20:29:39.688+01:00"
    tc, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000-07:00", t)

    fmt.Printf("t was %v and tc was %v", t, tc)

}
```

Comment: if I change 2006 to 2003, it failed to parse again. Why? https://play.golang.org/p/mv8kD63O4k

Comment: Because the string for year is `2006`.

Comment: Yeah you really have to use this specific date to specify the date string's format. It's a bit wonky, I think `YYYY` etc make formatting less clunky and error prone, but that's how it is.

Answer (score 5):

Your layout string is incorrect.  The numbers in the layout string have special meanings, and you are using `1` twice: once in the month portion and once in the time zone portion.  The time zone in the string you are parsing is `01:00`, so you are storing `1` into the month.  This explains why the returned month was January (the first month).

A corrected layout string is `2006-01-02T15:04:05.000-07:00`.  Or, if you're happy with using `Z` to represent UTC, the `time.RFC3339` constant might be appropriate.