# Is there any posibilities to change the default Bind timestamp format in gin-gionic?

Tags: json, go, go-gorm, go-gin

I have a question in Go especially with gin-gionic and gorm.

Let's say I have model like this

```golang
// Classroom struct.
type Classroom struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name      string    `json:"name"`
    Code      string    `json:"code"`
    StartedAt time.Time `json:"started_at"`
}
```

I want to create data of `Classroom` Model with this JSON

```json
{
  "name": "Math",
  "code": "math-mr-robie",
  "started_at": "2020-10-10 10:00:00"
}
```

But when I bind the JSON data, I got this following error

```
parsing time ""2020-10-10 10:00:00"" as ""2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"": cannot parse " 10:00:00"" as "T"
```

I know that error appear because of the format that I sent was not the exact format of `time.Time`?

Is it possible to set default format of `time.Time`?

How to do that?

Because I've try to add .Format in after `time.Time` but error occurs.

```golang
// Classroom struct.
type Classroom struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name         string `json:"name"`
    Code         string `json:"code"`
    StartedAt    time.Time.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05") `json:"started_at"`
}
```

Comment: There are many good solutions here [How to parse non standard time format from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45303326/how-to-parse-non-standard-time-format-from-json)

Comment: And in gin, you can do  https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#bind-query-string-or-post-data

Comment: Hi @Eklavya thank you for the comment. But know I have issue ```sql: converting argument $6 type: unsupported type models.JSONDate, a struct``` I try to look up for this [Go Gorm Custom Data Type](https://github.com/go-gorm/datatypes/blob/master/date.go)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this issue by creating new struct `JSONData` that contain time inside it.

```golang
// JSONData struct.
type JSONData struct {
  Time time.Time
}
```

After I red [Customize Data Types in Gorm](https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html) and see some examples [here](https://github.com/go-gorm/datatypes/blob/master/date.go) then I add some methods

```golang
// Scan JSONDate.
func (j *JSONDate) Scan(value interface{}) (err error) {
    nullTime := &sql.NullTime{}
    err = nullTime.Scan(value)
    *j = JSONDate{nullTime.Time}
    return
}

// Value JSONDate.
func (j JSONDate) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    y, m, d := time.Time(j.Time).Date()
    return time.Date(y, m, d, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.Time(j.Time).Location()), nil
}

// GormDataType gorm common data type
func (j JSONDate) GormDataType() string {
    return "timestamp"
}
```

For the gin things. Another [resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45303326/how-to-parse-non-standard-time-format-from-json) @Eklavya given. So I add another methods.

```golang
// UnmarshalJSON JSONDate.
func (j *JSONDate) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    s := strings.Trim(string(b), "\"")
    t, err := time.Parse(helpers.YMDHIS, s)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *j = JSONDate{
        Time: t,
    }
    return nil
}

// MarshalJSON JSONDate.
func (j JSONDate) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte("\"" + j.Time.Format(helpers.YMDHIS) + "\""), nil
}

// Format method.
func (j JSONDate) Format(s string) string {
    t := time.Time(j.Time)
    return t.Format(helpers.YMDHIS)
}
```

And it's works!

Comment: Using gin you can use _time_format_  Ex: _Birthday   time.Time `time_format:"2006-01-02"`_

Comment: @Eklavya I've try that one but can't still parse the time format I use. ```2006-01-02 15:04:05```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question with the same issue and found that if you are looking for a specific `time` format like the `ISOString`s sent from the browser you can have something like this;

```
type Classroom struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name      string    `json:"name"`
    Code      string    `json:"code"`
    StartedAt time.Time `json:"started_at" time_format:"RFC3339"`
}
```

With the `time_format` I did not need to define marshal functions to handle the formatting. However, if you need to do a completely custom format for your date and time then I believe you will need to define these functions.