# Convert date from DD-MON-YY to YYYYMMDD

Tags: date, go

In GoLang, how should I convert date from DD-MON-YY to YYYYMMDD format?

```
My input is: 9-Nov-17
Expected output is: 20171109
```

But when I do below:

```
t, err := time.Parse("20060102", "9-Nov-17")
```

Golang returns error:

```
Error: parsing time "9-Nov-17" as "20060102": cannot parse "v-17" as "2006"
```

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing date string in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845172/parsing-date-string-in-golang)

Comment: "9-Nov-17" is not a date in the format of "20060102" so of course you get an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to parse the time in the current format and then format it into the expected format using `Format` function

Check the answer below

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // Parse a time value from a string in dd-Mon-yy format.
    t, _ := time.Parse("2-Jan-06", "9-Nov-17")
    //Format and print time in yyyymmdd format
    fmt.Println(t.Format("20060102"))
}
```

play link here  : [goplayground](https://play.golang.com/p/QEcaOxA9yM)

Answer (score 2):

There something called `layout` while parsing and formatting `time` in `go`. This layout will always formatted based on `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006` time value. As example if you have input `2017 November 22`, then the layout should be`2006 January 02`:

```
// example 1          -- layout ---      --- input -----
t, err := time.Parse("2006 January 02", "2017 November 22")
// example 2
t, err := time.Parse("02-01-2006", "22-11-2017")
```

Comment: The [reference time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants) can also be thought of `01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700`, which is easy to remember (like counting from 1 to 7)

Comment: @tgogos: And `01/02 15:04:05PM '06 -0700` for 24-hour clocks (15 = 12 + 03).