# Parse datetime from string

Tags: go

I am trying to parse a date value that I read from another file. The format of the string is:

```
str := 2019-04-29 11:16:06.699920+0900
layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000Z"

t, err := time.Parse(layout, str)
// handle error
```

I get an error saying that +0900 cannot be parsed as Z. I tried using the following layout as well:

```
layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000+0000"
```

I can parse the datetime if I replace +0900 with Z but I don't want to lose the timezone. How can I parse the date of such format, keeping the timezone intact? Thanks.

EDIT:
[Parsing date string in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845172/parsing-date-string-in-go) has a good discussion on the layout used but doesn't address the alternatives to using Z that I needed.

Replacing Z with -0700 did the job.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing date string in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845172/parsing-date-string-in-go)

Comment: Use `-0700` instead of `Z` in layout

Comment: -0700 did the job. Thanks @Eklavya!

Comment: @user743414 I felt that question and the answers talked about why we need to use a certain date for the layout. I understood that, but I couldn't find how to extract timezones using the layout they discussed.

Comment: last line says **Replacing Z with -0700 did the job.** , You mean the issue is solved ?

Comment: Yes, the issue is solved.